# Speed up Ignite boot in Java

Tags: java, ignite

I am using Ignite 2.6.0 inside Tomcat 8.5.32.

As can be seen in catalina.out log [here](https://pastebin.com/TWdJPcAv) it takes three and a half minutes to start.

For development purposes, **is there any way to reduce this time?**

It´s not required that Ignite has any special configuration. Just the simplest one suitable for development in a single machine.

This is how I am initializing Ignite:

```
private IgniteConfiguration getConfiguration(final String cacheName, final CacheConfiguration cacheCfg) {
        TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder wmIpFind = new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder(true);
        try {
            wmIpFind.setAddresses(Arrays.asList(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()));
        } catch (IgniteSpiException | UnknownHostException e) {
            wmIpFind.setAddresses(Arrays.asList("127.0.0.1"));
        }
        TcpDiscoverySpi discoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
        discoverySpi.setNetworkTimeout(3000);
        discoverySpi.setReconnectCount(1);
        discoverySpi.setReconnectDelay(60000);
        discoverySpi.setClientReconnectDisabled(true);
        discoverySpi.setIpFinder(wmIpFind);
        IgniteConfiguration igniteConfig = new IgniteConfiguration();
        igniteConfig.setIgniteInstanceName("IgniteLocalhostServer");
        igniteConfig.setCacheConfiguration(cacheCfg);
        igniteConfig.setClientMode(false);
        igniteConfig.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(false);
        igniteConfig.setMetricsLogFrequency(0);
        igniteConfig.setDiscoverySpi(discoverySpi);
        igniteConfig.setMetricsLogFrequency(0);
        return igniteConfig;
    }
}
```

and then

```
CacheConfiguration<K,V> cacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<K,V>().setCacheMode(CacheMode.LOCAL).setName(name);
Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(getConfiguration(name, cacheCfg));
Cache<K,V> namedCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheCfg);
```

Comment: Not knowing about ignite specifically, the general advice would be: don't shut down things when starting up takes too long. In other words: would "hotswap" solutions work for you, such as JRebel? Why restarting your system when you can push your changes into a DEV instance on the fly ...

Comment: @GhostCat I am actually using DCEVM for dynamic class reload by putting JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Dcatalina.home=$CATALINA_HOME -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/apr/lib:/usr/share/hbase/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64 -XXaltjvm=dcevm -javaagent:/usr/share/tomcat/lib/hotswap-agent-1.3.0.jar=autoHotswap=true" in Tomcat init.d but often a full Tomcat re-start is still required.

Comment: Then: good luck here ... but I rather doubt that you can expect major performance boosts given the details you outlined so far.

Comment: There isn't much wiggle room to tweak startup performance, although 3.5 minutes for a single-node cluster seems like a lot. Try looking at the logs and see where does Ignite spend most of the time. Make sure to look at the Ignite logs (under `<ignite_work_dir>/logs`) or enable verbose mode (`-DIGNITE_QUIET=false`)

Answer (score 0):

First you have Catalina losing 1:30 between some benign log lines, and then Ignite spending another two minutes in the nowhere.

I would imagine that something external is happening here. Extremelly slow I/O? Hostnames that take forever to resolve? It is hard to say remotely.